# Is there an Elsevier LaTeX2e book class?

Tags: pdftex, lyx

I am interested in evaluating LaTeX2e book classes used by specific book publishers. I would like to lay my hands on the LaTeX2e book class, if it exists, for preparing book manuscripts for publication by the **Elsevier Publishers**. If such a class exists in the Internet then is there a LyX layout file for it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards to the TeX/LaTeX community.

Comment: Some information you should know: **If you intend to prepare your material using software other than Microsoft Word or WordPerfect, please consult us before you start writing.**, from the guidelines by Elsevier for book authors, to be found here: http://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/word_doc/0005/213917/Elsevier_ST_Books_Brief_Manuscript_Guidelines-revised_7-18.doc

Comment: Off-topic comment: There are three questions by you, all of them having good answers. It would be a good idea, to accept one of the answers for each question and not piling up questions ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much Christian. I am a bit surprised that Elsevier do not have a LaTeX book class in the public domain, when they do have a LaTeX article class in the public domain. Thanks for the advice. I'll desist from piling up my questions in future.

Comment: @user24098 to be clear, Christian is suggesting that you accept answers that answer your question. This is helpful when someone has the same problem and wants to know the solution that worked for you, and it's a way of thanking those that spent time trying to help you. To accept an answer, click on the green checkmark.

Comment: For a few of your questions, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89773/how-can-i-create-new-commands-in-tikz and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91650/how-can-i-get-access-to-the-size-parameters-of-a-tikz-node and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131419/why-does-lyx-flag-the-following-maths-macro-definition-as-an-error

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is, I'm afraid, that there does not appear to be an `elsbook` document class (or any other book-type document class provided by Elsevier).

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed an elsevier LaTeX. Otherwise, how could they receive and publish manuscripts in LaTeX in a uniform format? Their LaTeX is called Elsbook.cls etc. It is not available in the Internet. Go to their homepage and ask an Elsevier publishing editor.

Comment: That's a very old class file and as far as I know stopped being maintained almost 10 years ago. You submit your manuscript with class of your own choice and they do the typesetting internally. There is no such class file anymore

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer, regarding that the content is quite outdated.

Comment: https://github.com/vtex-soft/texsupport.elsevier-book